# Doctrine ORM, ManyToMany - duplicates on lazy fetch

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

Symfony 2.8. When using default fetch mode duplicates are returned (why?), using fetch="EAGER" - everything is ok.

I have following objects:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
(...)
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $role;

    public function addRole(\WerbeoBundle\Entity\Role $role)
    {
        $this->role[] = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRole(\WerbeoBundle\Entity\Role $role)
    {
        $this->role->removeElement($role);
    }

    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
```

Role:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Role
{
(...)
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="role")
     */
    private $users;

(... and getters/setters ...)
```

Now I have following table user_role:

```
user_id | role_id
      1 | ADMIN
      1 | EDITOR
```

When I call $user->getRole() result is

```
ADMIN
EDITOR
EDITOR
ADMIN
EDITOR
```

This happens in twig/controller only when using default fetch mode (lazy). When fetch="EAGER" everything is ok.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code that shows how you achieve incorrect results (controller/twig). Also you could check what queries are being run in both cases. You can check that in Symfony's profiler.

Comment: I noticed that this is probably kind of session/serialization problem - it affects only one User object - which I'm logged in. So problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if an entry already exists before adding

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this-role = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection()
}

public function addRole(\WerbeoBundle\Entity\Role $role)
{
    if(!$this->role->contains($role)){
       $this->role->add($role)
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be not but solution, but I have problem elsewhere. Even checking for Role duplicates in addRole I get duplicates roles but only for actually logged user. So there is maybe problem with User object stored in session.